# How can I assign a .NET 4 WinForm application to the owner property of a Delphi 7 form?

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, interop

I need to assign a .NET 4 Winform application as the owner of a Delphi 7 form.

I have created a .dll in Delphi which contains the form.  The Delphi .dll exports methods to create and display the form.

I have successfully loaded the Delphi .dll in my .NET app, and displayed the form.

Now I need to be able to assign the .NET app (or main form of the .NET app) as the owner of the Delphi form.

I have previously created a Delphi app that interops to .NET through COM, and assigns the Delphi app as the owner of the .NET forms using the following class:

```
public class WindowHandleWrapper : IWin32Window
{
    public HandleRef m_Handle;

    public IntPtr Handle
    {
        get
        {
            return m_Handle.Handle;
        }
    }

    public WindowHandleWrapper(IntPtr handle)
    {
        m_Handle = new HandleRef(this, handle);
    }
}
```

The Delphi application handle was passed as an integer to the `WindowHandleWrapper` constructor.

I suspect that the solution will be something similar, e.g. passing a handle to Delphi as an integer.  However, the Delphi type for the Owner property of a form is TComponent.  I'm just not exactly sure how to assign the .NET handle as the Delphi form's owner.

Any ideas?

Comment: What's wrong with `MyForm := TMyForm.Create(Application)`?

Comment: @David Heffernan: Because the WinForms Application isn't a VCL TApplication, and therefore the above won't work.

Comment: @Ken I don't think that matters. My Excel COM add-in DLL successfully uses TApplication.

Comment: And what's more, why does your form need an owner? Just pass nil to the constructor and free the form when you are done with it.

Comment: Maybe OP is confused between Owner and parent... @Welton, I have to ask, why do you want the .NET winform to be the *owner* and not the *parent* of the Delphi form?

Comment: My form needs an owner for a couple of reasons: first, to prevent the .NET form from being displayed on top of the Delphi form, when the Delphi form is displayed modally; also to prevent the Delphi form from creating a button on the Windows task bar.

Comment: @Welton Delphi Owner property has nothing to do with that.

Comment: Those reasons have nothing to do with Owner, in Delphi terms. You mean Parent. +1 @jachguate

Comment: @TOndrej I don't think the form wants to be parented at all. OP wants a top-level window, that doesn't appear in the taskbar. And a modal form. Problem is you need to disable the forms in the .net app.

Comment: @Welton I think you need to re-ask the question. What you actually want to ask is exactly what you said in your commment. Don't suggest possible solutions (e.g. owner, parent etc.). Just explain your problem and what your requirements are.

Comment: @David, it *does* matter. TCustomForm.Create is looking for a TComponent as AOwner, and since the WinForm app doesn't use the same memory manager the WinForm Application won't have the same VMT as TComponent, and therefore won't work. If you don't believe, try it (and post your code if it works - I'm not sure where, but it won't matter <g>).

Comment: Yes, after reading his comment, perhaps he just needs to assign the winform handle to Delphi's Application.Handle.

Comment: @Ken I think TOndrej might be onto something. I'm pretty sure that Add-in Express, as used by our COM add-in, does something similar.  Anyway I've no idea what your comment is about. In a DLL, `Application` exists and can be used as the owner to a form. It matters not one iota what the ultimate executable is.  It's not as if that executable can inject a different object into the VCL compiled into your DLL!

Comment: @Ken Yep, TOndrej has it. Add-in Express hunts for the Excel main window with `EnumThreadWindows` and then assigns it to `Application.Handle`.

Comment: @Welton I don't know if you can (or will), but it can't hurt to ask. I needed to to this for an application that I'm developing, but I was unable to get it working; could you give me some tips (or links, or even code maybe) on how to do this? I would reeaaally appreciate it. My email is pascaljr@gmail.com. Tks so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass your WinForm handle to the DLL as a parameter, and assign it to `Application.Handle` before creating and showing the form modally.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: It's a very old trick for showing a Delphi form from a DLL. I'm glad it helped you, cheers.

Comment: I worked on a project that used this technique extensively as a way to modularize the application. Each dll was practically an application unto itself. All the forms ran full screen modal and certain UI elements were standardized so it gave the appearance that it was a single form updating dynamically based on the user's actions.